# Sum Values by Key First X Characters (Python)

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like so (but much longer):

```
codes = {
    '113110': 7,    '113310': 1,    '213111': 1,
    '213112': 3,    '236115': 2,    '236220': 1,
    '238190': 1,    '238330': 1,    '238990': 2,
    '311612': 1,    '321214': 1,     }
```

I want to know the sum value of all keys grouped by the first two digits. So, '11' should be 8. But if I check like the following, an occurrence of '11' anywhere in the key will count.

```
group_11 = sum([ v for k,v in codes.items() if '11' in k])
# Returns 15 instead of 8
```

I've tried using `startswith`, but I'm not sure how it works in this context. Not like this:

```
group_11 = sum([ v for k,v in codes.items() if any(k.startswith('11')])
```

I have 20 groups to check against, but I want to be able to total any set of keys grouping by first x characters as the groupings could change in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to sort (the sorting is important for `groupby` to work properly) and group your `dict`'s items by the first two key chars and sum the values for each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {
    k: sum(item[1] for item in g) 
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(codes.items()), key=lambda item: item[0][:2])
}

d
{'11': 8, '32': 1, '31': 1, '21': 4, '23': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert all the items in `codes` to [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and sum them together:

```
from collections import Counter

codes = {
    '113110': 7,    '113310': 1,    '213111': 1,
    '213112': 3,    '236115': 2,    '236220': 1,
    '238190': 1,    '238330': 1,    '238990': 2,
    '311612': 1,    '321214': 1
}

sum((Counter({k[:2]: v}) for k, v in codes.iteritems()), Counter()) # Counter({'11': 8, '23': 7, '21': 4, '32': 1, '31': 1})
```